# Why is my scraper returning an empty list while trying to scrape from this website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My Code for the web scraper:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
 
url = "https://www.airtel.in/recharge-online?icid=header_new"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

[i.text for i in soup.select(".fs-lg icn-rupee")]
```

The URL I'm trying to scrape from is: https://www.airtel.in/recharge-online?icid=header_new
(an ISP's website listing plan prices)

The class I'm trying to scrape: **"fs-lg icn-rupee"**, which stores the numeric value for the price

Also, second, lesser important question, is it possible to scrape all tags having the class "fs-lg" using something like the ".find_all()" function (where tags having the class **"fs-lg"** as well as those having **"fs-lg icn-rupee"** are scraped) or would I have to do this through a separate call?

The output I'm currently receiving:

```
[]
```

My desired output would be the class and its contents which I would want to turn into a string using **".get_text()"** or something of the sort and then save that into a .csv file for later use.

Comment: If that element is loaded using JavaScript after the page loads, you'll need a library like selenium to execute the JavaScript to create that element.

Comment: Hi Carcigenicate, I'm really new to all of this stuff so it could well be the case I should have used selenium to execute the JS (which I do recall seeing somewhere in an output that js wasn't executed). How would you suggest I go about doing that and what basic resources would you recommend so that I can get to know more about selenium and how to use it in my particular application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website uses JavaScript, but `requests` doesn't support it. so we can use a library like [Requests-HTML](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/) to scrape the page.

Install it using `pip install requests-html`.

To also select the class `fs-lg` we can separate the CSS selector with a comma `,`. See this example:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://www.airtel.in/recharge-online?icid=header_new"
# Initialize an HTML Session
session = HTMLSession()
# Get the html content
response = session.get(URL)
# Execute JavaScript
response.html.render(sleep=3)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "lxml")

print([i.text for i in soup.select("p.fs-lg.icn-rupee, .fs-lg")])
```

Outputs:

```
['₹2498', '2GB', '365 Days', '₹1498', '24 GB', '365 Days', '₹698', '2GB', '84 Days', '₹598', '1.5GB', '84 Days', '₹558', '3GB', '56 Days', '₹449', '2GB', '56 Days', '₹399', '1.5GB', '56 Days', '₹398', '3GB', '28 Days', '₹379', '6GB', '84 Days', '₹349', '2GB', '28 Days', '₹298', '2GB', '28 Days', '₹289', '1.5GB', '28 Days', '₹279', '1.5GB', '28 Days', '₹249', '1.5GB', '28 Days', '₹219', '1GB', '28 Days', '₹199', '1GB', '24 Days', '₹179', '2GB', '28 Days', '₹149', '2GB', '28 Days', '₹129', '1GB', '24 Days', '₹19', '200 MB', '2 Days', '₹79', '200 MB', '28 Days', '₹49', '100 MB', '28 Days', '₹45', '0 MB', '28 Days', '₹401', '3 GB', '28 Days', '₹48', '3 GB', '28 Days', '₹5000', '₹4800', 'NA', '₹1000', '₹960', 'NA', '₹500', '₹480', 'NA', '₹100', '₹81.75', 'NA', '₹20', '₹14.95', 'NA', '₹10', '₹7.47', 'NA']
```

**Edit** using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/): install it using `pip install selenium`. Download the Chromedriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.airtel.in/recharge-online?icid=header_new"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")

print([i.text for i in soup.select("p.fs-lg.icn-rupee, .fs-lg")])

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hi Mendel, thanks for the input on the javascript part, I didn't know sites could vary like that! I tried your code out and there still seemed to be some runtime error that kept popping up: "Cannot use HTMLSession within an existing event loop. Use AsyncHTMLSession instead" which i looked into doing though somehow that too didn't fix the problem.. Would love to know if you did something different or if I'm missing something here..

Comment: I checked out chrome driver and it looks kinda sketchy especially with the fact I don't use vms and I mainly code on my privileged account.. Is it possible to run this code on jupyter without chromedriver as I ran your earlier code with the python shell and it worked fine

Comment: can you tell from experience how safe you found chrome driver? Are there any major flaws in its infrastructure that may pose certain vulnerabilities to my system in case somehow chrome driver becomes compromised?

Comment: @SomilVarshney it's open source. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/trunk/py

Comment: I followed your advice to use Selenium and dang it works perfectly! I'm able to even customize it to perfectly fit how I want it! I can't thank you enough for your time and effort!!!